# Decomposition of $k^*$-representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.
Let $V$ be an (algebraic) $k^*$-representation, not necessarily of finite dimension.

Is it true that $V$ decomposes in $k^*$-isotypical components:
$$ V = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} V_n $$where $V_n$ is the subspace of $V$ defined by
$V_n = \{ v \in V \; | \; \lambda \cdot v = \lambda^n v \; \; \forall \lambda \in k^* \}$?

If yes, why exactly $V$ splits like that? How do you prove that there is a finite dimensional invariant subspace of $V$?

Also, does this decomposition hold even if the $k^*$-action is not algebraic?

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "If yes, why exactly V splits like that? How do you prove that there is a finite dimensional invariant subspace of V?"

**Answer:** If $A:=k[t,1/t]$ it follows $G:=GL(1,k):=Spec(A)$ is an affine group scheme with $k$-rational points $G(k)=k^*$. The group scheme $G$ is reductive hence for any finite dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ there is a decomposition

$$V \cong \oplus_i V_i$$

where $V_i$ are irreducible $G$-modules. Since $G$ is abelian it follows $dim(V_i)=1$ hence $V$ decompose into a direct sum of characters of $G$.

If you consider $H:=k^*$ as an abstract abelian group, it follows an irreducible $H$-module $V$ is one dimensional. If $\# H:=d$ and $d \neq char(F)$ where $F$ is your base field, it follows any $H$-module $V \cong F^n$ decompose into a direct sum of one dimensional $H$-modules. Look up "Fulton/Harris - Representatin theory - a first course". The book gives many examples, references and is a good introduction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The finite dimensional case is pretty clear for me. I wondered if it holds in the non-finite dimensional case as well, at least in the case the $k^*$-action is algebraic.